# don't working backbutton listener

Tags: javascript, cordova

Why don't working EventListener?

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert1("A", "B");
        }

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

        function onBackKeyDown() {
            alert("A");
        }
</script>
```

i press my phone backbutton, don't floating alert. and, console log is

```
cordova.js:967 Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation
at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:967:40)
at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:958:5)
cordova.js:967 Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation
at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:967:40)
at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:958:5)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: are you sure backbutton course error?try comment and re run.

Comment: @FastSnail I checked, but I get an error when I press the back button. [link](http://youtu.be/taPhHWarb_0)

Comment: chan jang error may be some where else?try to find error in your script not in cordova js .

Comment: @FastSnail cordova.js error line is
`var msgs = nativeApiProvider.get().retrieveJsMessages(bridgeSecret, !!opt_fromOnlineEvent);`
and this **retrieveJsMessages(bridgeSecret, !!opt_fromOnlineEvent);**

Comment: chan jang there is no error in posted code.here is a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/jtK0Uct.png.you have to find code which cause the error.yes there is a error line in cordova js but there should be a error in your script that's why cordova shows a error